# Copy two remote folder into one local folder

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, replication, deployment, dfs

I try to merge two folder (from remote Server) into one local directory. It is a deployment issue, on one Server there are two folders \server1\folder1 and \server1\folder2, now i try to merge both folder into c:\NewFolder how can i solve this issue without any Tools like rsync or so?

Can i add something like virtualFolder or symlink who link to the content of this two folders?

THX
Rene

Answer (score 0):

It can be made with subst , please see this example http://www.codejacked.com/quick-tip-assign-a-drive-letter-to-a-folder-windows/ .

Hope this helps .

Comment: THX, but with SUBST i only can assign a folder to a drive letter. But i want to merge two remote folder to ONE local Folder. With SUBST i can't add a second Folder to the created drive

Comment: You could go with the creation of symbolic links http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/ .Exaple mklink /prefix link_path file/folder_path .